# IE9 simple click/scroll issue

Tags: jquery, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Personally, I am not experiencing this issue (Windows 7 with native IE9) but another computer is. Possibly Windows 7 but definitely IE9. Initially, the scroll buttons do not work on their machine. If they change their document and browser renderer to IE8 or IE7 if works fine then. If they change it back to IE9, it works. If they close out of the tab and reopen it fresh, it doesn't work again. Their console log is empty except for a syntax error deep within jQuery 1.4 which appears in all browsers and which I THINK is benign.

So my question is, can anyone replicate the issue or can find any reason why this is happening? Code and link to follow:

http://www.friedmanllp.com/home2.php

```
<div style="float:left; padding:0; width:20px !important; height:310px !important; text-align:left;">
    <div id="scroll_up" style="cursor:pointer;"><img style="margin:10px 0 270px 0;" src="images/arrow_up.png" /></div>
    <div id="scroll_down" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images/arrow_down.png" /></div>
</div>

$(function() {
    var ele   = $('#scroller');
    var speed = 25, scroll = 5, scrolling;

    $('#scroll_up').click(function() {
        //console.log("Up");
        // Scroll the element up

        var topPos = $('#scroller').scrollTop();
        console.log(topPos);    
        $("#scroller").animate({
            scrollTop: topPos - 200
        }, 800);
    });

    $('#scroll_down').click(function() {
        //console.log("Down");
        // Scroll the element down

        var topPos = $('#scroller').scrollTop();
        console.log(topPos);    
        $("#scroller").animate({
            scrollTop: topPos + 200
        }, 800);
    });

    $('#scroll_up, #scroll_down').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            // Prevent the default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            if (scrolling) {
                window.clearInterval(scrolling);
                scrolling = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

---

Comment: To solve that "deep" error, just get rid of the `@` in the selector: `[@href*=concentric]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try removing (or commenting out) any console.log() references in your code.

Without developer tools open IE will throw a fit as the console doesn't exist. With developer tools open the console DOES exist so no errors are thrown. I once spent a loooong time trying to debug a similar issue :)

Comment: +1 You can use this: http://www.illyriad.co.uk/blog/index.php/2011/01/javascript-avoiding-console-is-undefined/

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to both of you. Is it that only IE causes errors or that other browsers suppress them because it's the logical thing to do? Just curious is all.

Comment: I build a small wrapper that checks if console is present and if not, it adds the debug messages to an internal queue. I always call that just to be sure, that way you don't have to remove the code and you can get debug messages even if a user doesn't have dev tools open just by building a small environment reporter thing or telling them on the phone/email how to send the debug messages :)